# Invoke multiple powershell commands from c# on the same scope

Tags: powershell

Basically what I want to do is:

Step 1) Invoke whatever.ps1 (or a scriptblock), the script is something like:
$hello = "world"

Step 2) Invoke Get-Variable -name hello

Step 3) Retrieve the output of Get-Variable

I can't figure out how to do this cleanly, because every time I invoke a scriptblock a differente scope is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  Easiest is to change the script if you can to:

```
$global:hello = "world"
```

However using globals is generally a bad practice.  So another approach is to have your script output "Hello" and then capture the output the pipeline invocation.  Just change your initial script to this:

```
"world"
```

Then invoke it and grab the output of pipeline.Invoke() and grab the first object.

You could also change the way you invoke the script.  Pass in a string to CreatePipeline that looks like this:

```
$hello = foo.ps1
```

Then retreive the contents of variable $hello.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want a global (the other answer covers this) you don't need to use `Get-Variable` from your host application.

Create a Runspace and execute the script.

You can then access variables from the runspace:

```
value = myRunspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("name");
```

Comment: A limitation is that currently do not myRunspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable work on remote runspaces, it throws NewNotImplemented

Comment: Fastforward: not sure when this was finally implemented, but this command works in Powershell 5